# Gravar Video e Fazer Upload em C# MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc, upload

- Tenho que gravar um vídeo de 5s pela webcam, após a gravação fazer o upload deste vídeo para uma pasta.
- Já Pesquisei Vários Plugins em JS,

  - Usei este " https://github.com/muaz-khan/RecordRTC/blob/master/simple-demos/php-upload-simple-javascript.html "
- Só que não sei como posso Fazer o Upload deste vídeo em uma função no meu Controller, Existe Algum modo de fazer isso usando html e depois upar ele para um pasta do meu projeto? ou alguma outra forma.
- Projeto está em Asp.Net MVC

Answer (score 0):

Bom, considerando que a biblioteca retorna o aquivo como um input file, o que você pode fazer para salva-lo sem submeter o mesmo é utilizando [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/Window.localStorage).
Como você não deixou mais detalhes sobre seu código, vou deixar [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31850732/save-a-file-image-to-localstorage-html) um exemplo de sua utilização.

Agora, para salva-lo em "seu projeto", como o browser roda no cliente, não é possível salvar o arquivo diretamente em seu servidor, para isso será necessário fazer o upload do mesmo para sua aplicação, o enviando para o Controller. Segue [exemplo](https://www.devmedia.com.br/asp-net-mvc-4-realizando-upload-e-download-de-arquivos/30244).

Vale ressaltar que no próprio repositório já tem a implementação em MVC: [RecordRTC-to-ASPNETMVC](https://github.com/muaz-khan/RecordRTC/tree/master/RecordRTC-to-ASPNETMVC)

Comment: Não postei o código pois testei vários, Esse Script que usei ele, grava o vídeo e envia para um servidor php e retorna o Link do Vídeo.

Comment: Sim, o que você deve fazer para obter esse resultado é transcrever o processo de upload para o PHP em .NET, conforme o exemplo citado. Porém, como você disse que não poderia usar sua Controller, a unica alternativa é salva-lo localmente, que pode ser feito com local storage. No caso, é preciso avaliar sua necessidade, ao que me aparenta, você precisa recuperar o vídeo depois, então realmente tem que ser feito seu submit.

Comment: Escrevi errado posso usar sim a controller

Comment: Cara, da uma olhada no repositório MVC da biblioteca :)